# Create Simple Ping

Tags: c#, ping

How to create a simple ping to website and get is online or not?

Ex:

```
var test = new ping()
try{
test.ping(www.google.com)
messagebox.show("your internet connection is ok");
}
catch
{
messagebox.show("you are not connected");
}
```

it is possible? i have searched on the web but not found nothing

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) class to make an HTTP request and see if it succeeds.

Note that 'ping' is really an ICMP function, and not what you're looking for, if you're testing websites (HTTP).  If you really *do* want to just see if you have a connection, then ping will work, and the [`Ping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx) class, as [squiguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1114966/squiguy) mentioned.